# Configuration that builds both Debug and Release versions?

Tags: clion

Can I make a build configuration in CLion that builds both Debug and Release verions?

By default "Build All" only builds Debug. I can change it to build Release instead, but that's not what I want. I want a *single* configuration that builds *both* Debug and Release.

The problem is that otherwise, my Debug and Release versions may get out of sync, which can lead to confusions later on.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Before Launch -> Run Another Configuration to add your other Debug/Release configuration.

[image: Run Another Configuration]

Comment: Ideally I'd like to build "All Targets" in Debug and Release.  Unfortunately "Run Another Configuration" needs to be manually kept in sync with new targets.  Any ideas?